# Not able to create Chart Region(Donut Chart)- Cannot See label and Value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle **APEX build v21.1**  and **APEX_LISTENER_VERSION:21.2.0.r1741826** and I am trying to create a any chart like Donut chart with the below simple query :

```
select
    rownum  as value,
    rownum || ' label' as label
from
    dual
connect by level <= 3
```

but I not able to **see and select** the columns on right panel like LABEL and VALUE:

[image]

Note that I was able to create it before but I don't know if it is related to the APEX setup or not since it is a new setup

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you at least *try* to **select** label and value? Like this (left side of the screenshot), so that the result looks like its right side:

[image]

Comment: Of course I did.. and nothing is there

Comment: Here's what I did: created a **region** (type: chart; Source type: SQL query - pasted your query in there). **Series** was automatically created. I set its source to "Region Source", and then - in "Label" and "Value" properties for "Column Mapping", I saw LABEL and VALUE in select lists. Chose them, ran the report - you can see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I already created many charts before, but I faced this issue only after the DBA created a new APEX Instance in  a new server.

Comment: This issue will come if it reads from SQL Query only and not from a table

Comment: Aha. I created that chart on my 18.2. I'll try to do so on apex.oracle.com and see the outcome. Hold on.

Comment: Yes, it works there as well (version is 21.2.5). I wouldn't know if it is related to Apex installation ... I, somehow, doubt it - why would it cause chart's label not to be visible? Strange ...

Comment: I think it is ORDS installation problem. and it is very Slow while trying to validate the query in Series.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help with that. Perhaps you should talk to your DBA and see what they can do about it.

Comment: You're welcome; I hope you'll make it work. Good luck!